# How can I prove $\delta_{\lambda} \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How can I prove, formally, by its definition, that $\delta_{\lambda}=\delta(x-\lambda)$ is a distribution in $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R})$ for every $\lambda$ where I choose to center my distribution?

Comment: What does $\delta_\lambda$ mean? Is this what we often informally write as \delta(x-\lambda)$? Are you restricting to the reals?

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited the question; and yes, I am looking on $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: You need to show that $\delta_\lambda \in \mathcal[{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and that $\operatorname{supp} \delta_\lambda$ is compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, it's clear that $\delta_\lambda$ is a distribution, through the same argument as $\delta_0$ ($=\delta$). Also, $\text{supp}\  \delta_\lambda=\{\lambda\}$ (in the same way as $\text{supp}\ \delta_0=\{0\}$), which is compact. So, $\delta_\lambda\in\mathcal{E}'$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can show it is a continuous linear functional on the space $\mathscr{E}(\mathbb{R})$. The topology of this space can be defined by the collection of seminorms
$$
||f||_{k,m}=\max_{0\le j\le k}\ \max_{x\in [-m,m]}|f^{(j)}(x)|
$$
for $k,m$ nonnegative integers.
The linear map $\delta_{\lambda}:f\mapsto f(\lambda)$ satisfies
$$
|\delta_{\lambda}(f)|\le ||f||_{0,m}
$$
for fixed $m$ chosen such that $|\lambda|\le m$. So $\delta_{\lambda}$ is continuous and belongs to the topological dual $\mathscr{E}'(\mathbb{R})$.